# Visual Studio Code - how to prevent breaking lines excessively

Tags: visual-studio-code

As much as I like Visual Studio Code, one thing that I find annoying is that when formatting code it some times breaks lines excessively. I like compact code because it is IMO easier to read. When lines are broken to the extent as follows it is IMO counter-productive and unsightly and draws attention to those lines excessively. Is there a way to prevent this other than not using it's formatter (IE. don't break lines)?

```
Dart:
const List<String> lsMonths = [
  "Jan",
  "Feb",
  "Mar",
  "Apr",
  "May",
  "Jun",
  "Jul",
  "Aug",
  "Sep",
  "Oct",
  "Nov",
  "Dec"
];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18261) on VS Code typescript/javascript formatter. I rekon this feature is under development, and will be available soon. There is another option, to use another formatter other than vscode formatter: [js-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify). It has [directive to ignore or reserve sections](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify#directives).

Comment: The other issue is - do many people want their code to be formatted like that? I for one definitely don't and find it very frustrating to the point of changing my code - which wastes time.